# Prevent rails automatically converting url eg. & to %26 and = to %3D

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I have a rails application where I have urls stored in the database like this :

```
&utf8=✓&search_data[title]=&search_data[section_id]=2&search_data[status]=
```

now I have links which I would like to point to this url. But when I do it, instead of going to the url its converting everything to some other format looking like this :

```
%26utf8%3D✓%26search_data[title]%3D%26search_data[section_id]%3D2%26search_data[status]%3D
```

How can I prevent this from happening.